# Verify if user follow without a Exists SQL request

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm trying to build a following action into my apps. To achieve that, I used the most common way, a join table (:followers) to link the users and the posts.

But I'm encountering a little problem of efficience. Because for each of my posts, It's generating a Exists request to see if my user is following the current_post.

So I would like to know if there is a better solution to solve this request in one time ?

**My code :**

*Post/controller :*

```
  def index
    @my_user = current_user
    @posts = @group.posts.order(upd_at: :desc).includes(:user).includes(:followers)
  end
```

*Index view :*

```
<% @posts.each do |post|%>
       <%- if post.followers.where(user_id: current_user.id).any?%>
          <div class="btn btn-default pull-right" style="margin-top:-100px;">
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        <% else %>
          <div class="btn btn-default pull-right" style="margin-top:-100px;">
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking for `include?`..

```
<%- if post.followers.pluck(:user_id).include?(current_user.id)%>
```

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what i'm looking for !! Thanks for your answer @Md. Farhan Memon

Comment: Are you sure that's more efficient than an existence query? That will pull all the follower `user_id`s out of the database and then scan that array for `current_user.id`. That would pull more data out of the database and probably require the database to do more work to find that data.